# rspec giving undefined method

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

RSpec noob needs help. My brain is mush right now...I'm trying to create a basic "I exist and I return a value" set of test for this method in my code...

```
def attempt_win(board)
 @ai_winmoves.each do |k, v| # go through each win move in the ai_winmoves array located above.         
   ai_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "O"}.keys # grab all computer player's Os from the value hash

   intersection = ai_keys & @keys_with_o # get common elements between two arrays..note: keys_with_o = all current O's on game board

   if intersection.length >=2 # when two intersections exist it means two O's are on the board

    @answers_array << k # add to answers array per iteration

    @answers_array.each do |key|
      # answer = @anskey[@thing.last].to_sym
      puts "which moves can ai win with?"
      puts @anskey[key]
      answer = @anskey[key].to_sym
      puts "attempt win"
      puts answer

      if board.grid[answer] == " " #if win move space is empty take it
        @move = answer               
      else #check for a block move  
        # attempt_block    # handled at line 162               
      end
    end
  end
end # END @ai_winmoves.each do |k,v|
```

end

Here is my test code...

```
  describe 'attempt_win' do
    before (:each) do
      @board.grid[:b2] == "X"
    end 
    xit 'computer looks for any possible win move'
    it 'computer returns a value' do
      @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should_not be(nil)
    end
  end
```

here is the rspec failure I'm getting...

```
    1) Player class attempt_win computer returns a value
 Failure/Error: @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should_not be(nil)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # ./lib/player.rb:171:in `attempt_win'
 # ./spec/player_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

THAT'S IT BUT.....

IF YOU WANT TO SEE THE ENTIRE CLASS FILE player.rb and it's test file player_spec.rb LOOK BELOW...

```
# TODO - send error output if move already taken
# TODO - better WIN detection

class Player

attr_reader :boardpiece # i exist so game.rb can read me

def initialize(letter)
  @boardpiece = letter
end

def move_human(game, board)
  @game_two = game

  puts "human move..."

  human_move = gets.chomp
  human_symbol = human_move.to_sym
  # look for move as key in board.grid
  if board.grid.has_key?(human_symbol)
    if board.grid[human_symbol] == " "
      #puts "bingo"  
      @move = human_symbol            
    else
      puts "spot taken...try again"
      move_human(@game_two, board)
    end
  else
    puts "invalid move...try again"
    move_human(@game_two, board)
  end           
end


def move_computer(game, board)
  # ai should do three things
  # attempt win
  # block human
  # random move

  puts "computer move..."
  # all possible third moves as 'O' (computer)
  @human_winmoves = {
      :wm01 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm02 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm03 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm04 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm05 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm06 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm07 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm08 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      #check those corners
      :wm09 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm10 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm11 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm12 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm13 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm14 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm15 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm16 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      #check opposites
      :wm17 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm18 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm19 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm20 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm21 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm22 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm23 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm24 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      #check crazy
      :wm25 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm26 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm27 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm28 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},            
      :wm29 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm30 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm31 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm32 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm33 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm34 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm35 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
      :wm36 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
      :wm37 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm38 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm39 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm40 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "}
  }

  @ai_winmoves = {
      :wm01 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm02 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm03 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm04 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm05 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm06 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm07 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm08 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      #check those corners
      :wm09 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm10 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm11 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm12 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm13 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm14 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm15 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm16 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      #check opposites
      :wm17 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm18 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm19 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm20 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm21 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm22 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm23 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm24 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      #check crazy
      :wm25 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm26 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm27 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm28 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},            
      :wm29 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm30 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm31 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm32 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm33 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm34 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm35 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
      :wm36 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
      :wm37 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm38 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm39 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
      :wm40 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "}
  }
  # match current answers located in @thegrid with possible @anskey array, iterate for each item
  @anskey={
      :wm01=>"c3",:wm02=>"c2",:wm03=>"c1",:wm04=>"b3",:wm05=>"b1",:wm06=>"a3",:wm07=>"a2",:wm08=>"a1",
      :wm09=>"a3",:wm10=>"c1",:wm11=>"a1",:wm12=>"c3",:wm13=>"c3",:wm14=>"c1",:wm15=>"c3",:wm16=>"a1",
      :wm17=>"b1",:wm18=>"b2",:wm19=>"b3",:wm20=>"a2",:wm21=>"b2",:wm22=>"b2",:wm23=>"c2",:wm24=>"b2",
      :wm25=>"a1",:wm26=>"a1",:wm27=>"a3",:wm28=>"a3",:wm29=>"c1",:wm30=>"c1",:wm31=>"c3",:wm32=>"c3",
      :wm33=>"a1",:wm34=>"a1",:wm35=>"c1",:wm36=>"c1",:wm37=>"a3",:wm38=>"a3",:wm39=>"c3",:wm40=>"c3"
  }
  #
  # scan board for available move locations
  @keys_with_o = board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == "O" }.keys       # find Os on the board

  @keys_with_x = board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == "X" }.keys       # find Xs on the board

  @answers_array = [] # initialize answers array

  if board.grid[:b2] == " "   #AND center spot is empty
    ai_spot = "b2"
    # puts "ai takes center "+ai_spot
    @move = ai_spot.to_sym  #must return this answer as a symbol         
  else
    # TODO - Ai attempts win
    i = 0
    until i == 4
      attempt_win(board) #run 3x then run attempt_block
      i = i+1 # add 1 to i
      if i == 4
        puts "running attempt_block..." 
        attempt_block(board)
      end
    end
  end

  return @move # had this guy in the wrong place
end      

def attempt_win(board)
  @ai_winmoves.each do |k, v| # go through each win move in the ai_winmoves array above.         
    ai_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "O"}.keys # grab all computer player's Os from the value hash

    intersection = ai_keys & @keys_with_o # get common elements between two arrays..note: keys_with_o = all current O's on game board

    if intersection.length >=2 # when two intersections exist it means two O's are on the board

      @answers_array << k # add to answers array per iteration

      @answers_array.each do |key|
        # answer = @anskey[@thing.last].to_sym
        puts "which moves can ai win with?"
        puts @anskey[key]
        answer = @anskey[key].to_sym
        puts "attempt win"
        puts answer

        if board.grid[answer] == " " #if win move space is empty take it
          @move = answer               
        else #check for a block move  
          # attempt_block    # handled at line 162               
        end
      end
    end
  end # END @ai_winmoves.each do |k,v|
end

def attempt_block(board)
  puts "attempt block method - hi"
  # thing = [] # initialize thing array
  @human_winmoves.each do |k,v| # for test - go threw each win moves.
    # get common elements between two arrays..recall from above that v contains a hash
    human_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "X"}.keys
    # which moves can I take to block human
    intersection = human_keys & @keys_with_x

    if intersection.length >= 2
      puts "intersection"
      puts intersection
      @answers_array << k # adds a key per iteration
      puts "@answers_array << k"
      puts @anskey[k]
      @answers_array.each do |key|
        puts "which moves can ai block with?"
        puts @anskey[key]
        answer = @anskey[key].to_sym
        puts "attempt block"
        puts answer

        # if board.spot_taken?(answer)

        if board.grid[answer] != " " # spot taken
          puts "space taken can not block 2: " + answer.to_s 
        else
          puts answer.to_s+" blocked"
          @move = answer # for test - at last intersection value found...return it as move value
          return @move
        end
      end
    end
  end # END @human_winmoves.each do |k,v|
end 
end
```

If you wanna see the entire player_spec.rb file...

```
require 'game'
require 'board'

describe 'Player class' do  
before (:each) do
  #Dry it up
  @player_human = Player.new('X')
  @player_computer = Player.new('O')
  @board = Board.new
  @game = Game.new(@player_human, @player_computer, @board)
end

describe 'move_human' do
  before (:each) do
    # first set up my expectations         
    @player_human.should_receive(:puts).with("human move...")
    @player_human.stub(:gets).and_return("a1")
  end
  it 'receives cli input and prints text to screen' do
    # now trigger them
    @player_human.move_human("X", @board)
  end
  it 'returns a move value' do
    # now trigger them
    @player_human.move_human("X", @board).should eq(:a1)     #return the value is what I mocked?
  end     
end

describe 'move_computer' do
  it 'should print - ...computer move... - to screen' do
    # first set up my expectations
    @player_computer.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move...")
    # now trigger them
    @player_computer.move_computer("O", @board)
  end
  it 'returns expected first move b2' do
    @player_computer.move_computer("O", @board).should eq(:b2)
  end
end

describe 'attempt_win' do
  before (:each) do
    @board.grid[:b2] == "X"
  end 
  xit 'computer looks for any possible win move'
  it 'computer returns a value' do
    @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should_not be(nil)
  end
end

describe 'attempt_block'do
  xit 'looks for a block move'
end
end
```

Comment: I would suggest running it in debug.  If you haven't done that before read up on it.  It will help you tremendously to be able to solve this and future problems.

Comment: is this it? ... http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/366-ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui-

Comment: You know, giving us this much code to read... You need to narrow it down first. You do that by gradually simplifying the program, deleting the sections that are not causing the error and isolating the shortest possible piece of code + test code that still gives the same error. At that point, either (1) you will yourself understand the reason why the error appears, or (2) you will still not understand the error, and you ask it on SO. I cannot really upvote your question as it stands.

Comment: agree with @Boris Stitnicky, this is too much code. You've got to try a bit harder to narrow down where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @Boris the first three blocks are "the offending method", "the suspect test" and "the offending error"....I don't think it gets any smaller than that ;)....the last two code blocks are the entire class and it's related spec...as many devs ask to see that when  coders only place the specific suspicious code.

Comment: @thefonso: Up to the point that your error is obviously caused by either `@ai_winmoves` or `@answers_array` instance variable being equal to `nil`, and none of these are explicitly initialized in either of your first three blocks, so the answerer would need to read all of your class code, which you conveniently posted. Besides, we have no idea which of your lines is line 171. And no, I'm not answering this question, bye, you won't be seeing me around this question anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you pretty clearly what is wrong, if you know how to read it right:

```
1) Player class attempt_win computer returns a value
 Failure/Error: @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should_not be(nil)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # ./lib/player.rb:171:in `attempt_win'
 # ./spec/player_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is telling you several things:

- The line of your spec where the error occurred is `@player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should_not be(nil)`.
- The error is due to `each` being called on an object that does not respond to that message.
- The object it was called on is `nil`.
- The error occurred at `./lib/player.rb:171` in the `attempt_win` method, or in some internal library method called by `attempt_win`. (You can run your spec with the `--backtrace` flag to get the full backtrace. By default, RSpec tries to filter it to only the relevant lines to reduce noise.)

Looking at your code, the error suggests that `@ai_winmoves` has not been initialized and had the value of `nil` when `attempt_win` was called.